How to disable the link from product title in WooCommerce Archives
I would like to develop wooCommerce custom plugin. For the project requirement product title hyperlink will be disable.For this simple task i define the following script.Please give me the solution How to fix this.I want to use it WordPress custom plugin.
class Custom_WooCommerce_Disable_Title_Link {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'remove_title_hyperlink' ) );
    }

    public function remove_title_hyperlink() {

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
    }
}

new Custom_WooCommerce_Disable_Title_Link();

I tried about above script. this is doesn't work

Your provided code works with most themes, so the issue in your case is because of your theme own customizations related to WooCommerce.

Hope this resides in a plugin and it's active?

@LoicTheAztec yes already use it in the theme but I want to use it in the custom plugin. that's it not working

The following code has been tested in a custom plugin (Tested with Storefront theme, on last WordPress and WooCommerce versions). It works also in functions.php file of a child theme.
To disable the product link only for product titles from WooCommerce Archive pages, use the following:
 class WC_Loop_Product_Title_No_Link {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'remove_link_from_product_title' ) );
    }

    public function remove_link_from_product_title() {
        // Close link before product title
        add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
        // Open link after product title
        add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 20 );
    }
}

new WC_Loop_Product_Title_No_Link();

Note that this will not work with some themes that have their own related customizations.

thats good this is working thank you. @LoicTheAztec
